# Can someone explain the working of this code?

Tags: javascript

So, I know this is related to higher order functions in JS, but I just don't understand how we're passing a value for `m` here.  Also, after we declare a variable `greaterThan10`, what does passing values to it do?

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

Comment: Maybe `return function greaterThanN(m) { return m > n; }` would've been clearer. Do you understand that?

Comment: `greaterThan(10)(11) -> true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m => m > n` is shorthand syntax for a **function**.
This means that calling `greaterThan(10)` will create a function that could also be written like this:

```
function greaterThan10(m) {
  return m > 10; // this is still `m > n`, however, `n` cannot be changed from outside of the scope
}
```

Basically, `m` will be the parameter of the function returned by `greaterThan(10)` and `n` is the value passed to it, in this case `10`.

The technical term is ***arrow function expression***. You can read more about it on [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).